# Insert vCard in Android

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to import and export contact on an Android phone as vCards. Export works fine and I get the vCard string.

But how can I insert a contact from a vCard string? I wasn't able to find any sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Google tells me there seems to be a [library](http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/) doing what you need.

Comment: that lib is just a parser, not an import / export facility.

Comment: when you've parsed the vcard, you just have to add the contact. You can find other questions that will help you in this task.